# Is there a way to use parameters in custom \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

One way to [write custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules) in Laravel is by calling Artisan method `make:rule`:

```
php artisan make:rule EmptyIf
```

Then I don't know how to handle parameters. "Parameters" means something like `require_if:foo,bar`. The `\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule` interface has only two arguments for `passes` function:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value);
```

So I can't understand where I should add parameters. I know I can extends the validator via a Service provider, just like this:

```
Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) { 
    //
});
```

But it seems it's an old way, and in my point of view a bit more messy. Is there a way to handle parameter in `passes` function of a `Rule`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define constructor for your custom rule and then pass your paramets in custom rule object.
**Custom rule:**

```
class CustomRule implements Rule
{
    private $params = [];

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }    

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return /*Here you can use $this->params*/;
    }
}
```

**Validation:**

```
$request->validate([
    'input' => ['rule', new CustomRule(['param1','param2','paramN'])],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something like this:

```
protected $validationRules = [
        'name' => 'required|myRule:a,b',
];
```

I call my rule from inside my service provider book() method:

```
Validator::extend(
    'myRule',
    function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $rule = new MyRule();
        $rule->setA($parameters[0])
            ->setB($parameters[1]);
        return $rule->passes($attribute, $value);
    },
    MyRule::errorMessage()
);
```

The rule looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

/**
 * Check if an encoded image string is a valid image
 */
class EncodedImage implements Rule
{
    public function setA($a){}
    public function setB($b){}

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return self::errorMessage();
    }

    /**
     * Static so the ServiceProvider can read it.
     */
    public static function errorMessage()
    {
        return 'The :attribute is not valid';
    }
}
```